# How to fetch below json and store it using Realm? I am having difficulty just need data part

Tags: android, json, database, realm

I am new to Realm and been trying to store json data directly to database for future use and thought of implementing Realm for first  time but, I don't know like how to fetch this nested data as, I want only data array section. This is the json to be fetched and saved:

```
{
status: 200,
message: {
success: Demos sent successful."
},
data: [
{
vStoryName: "D1",
vStoryUrl: "http://demo.com/demo.png",
tStoryDetail: "data1"
},
{
vStoryName: "D2",
vStoryUrl: "http://demo.com/demo.png",
tStoryDetail: "data2"
},
{
vStoryName: "D3",
vStoryUrl: "http://demo.com/demo.png",
tStoryDetail: "data3"
}
]
}
```

Comment: Deserialize the object and call `insertOrUpdate()` on the deserialized `data`

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
public class Story extends RealmObject {
  public String vStoryName;
  public String vStoryUrl;
  public String vStoryDetail;
}

String httpResult = getHttpResult();
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(httpResult);
JSONArray data = obj.getJSONArray("data");
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.createAllFromJson(Story.class, data);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

But given how the JSON looks I would probably deserialize it using something like GSON instead.